# How to get position in column from SQlite query?

Tags: android, arrays, string, sqlite

IN SQLITE DATABASE

```
public String getAllNames() {
    String selectQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM LIST ORDER BY nametype";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor2 = database.rawQuery(selectQuery2, null);
    if (cursor2.moveToFirst()) {
        return cursor2.getString(15);//NAMES
    }
    database.close();
    return cursor2.getString(15);//NAMES
}
```

IN NAME.JAVA

```
TextView menutype =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.menutype);
String m =controller.menuitems();
menutype.setText(m+"");
```

SO how do I get the position of the NAMES so I can set String m based on position 1, 2 or whatever. What I am doing is using OnTouchListener left or right swipe to get the next or previous name in my query then using a textListener to change the view based on what String m is.

Comment: Downvotes are sometimes more baffling than the questions.

Comment: Did you try checking the documentation? Use the `Cursor` method `getColumnIndex(String name)`.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getColumnIndex(java.lang.String)

Comment: I suspect somebody (not me) downvoted the question as you don't seem to have done any research.

Comment: position in column...not of

Comment: Sorry but your comment doesn't make sense. If you want the index of a column name then use `getColumnIndex(...)`

Comment: you could google to get an answer, you posted here, okay! But your question is uncompleted.

Comment: Agreed...time to delete. I am asking the wrong question. I know the columnIndex..it's 15 and obvious.  I need a list of all the NAMES that make up column 15 then I need to get the position of the NAMES not their column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ou can execute cursor.moveToPosition(int pos) and move cursor to needeed row and than retrive name from moved cursor. 
If i misunderstood you and you just want to get position of column "names" in a database => cursor.getColumnIndex(String columnName)

Comment: 2 months later and I finally realize what you meant !